# Range.Replace not working as expected on Office 365 version

Tags: excel, vba

I have a somewhat complex worksheet that has been behaving for my client for over a year now and recently they reported an issue to me that has me baffled.

The workbook creates a copy of it self and then goes though a number of weekly tasks to remove completed tasks and to promote tasks due this week.

The final step is to change a number of characters in a named range.

The code:

```
Sub No_More_Delays()  
    Range("Com_stat").Replace What:="D", Replacement:="X"
    Range("Com_stat").Replace What:="L", Replacement:="X"
    Range("Com_stat").Replace What:="W", Replacement:="X"
End Sub
```

The symptoms are that only the first "hit" works.  So if there is a `D` in any of the cells then all of the `D`'s get changed to `X`, however, if there are no `D`'s and only `L`'s then all of the `L`'s get replaced and if there are no `D` or `L`'s the all of the `W`'s get replaced.  If there are  `D`'s, `L`'s and `W`'s only the `D`'s get replaced.  If I change the order of the commands and put the `W` first and the `D` last and there are `D`'s, `L`'s and `W`'s all of the `W`'s get replaced and nothing else.

These symptoms only occur at the clients office where they subscribe to Office 365.  On my machine running the same OS and a non Office 365 version of Excel, everything works.

Has anyone else experienced anything like this and if you have is there a work-around.

Comment: Maybe the first line raises an error (due to whatever reason) which is suppressed. Are the following lines executed?

Comment: Try to also set `LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False` Excel remembers the last state of `LookAt` and you never know what it is until you specified it.

Comment: Also reference what ever sheet you are working on

Comment: @0m3r If the Range Name is of workbook scope, that won't be necessary.